# Trouble getting the chart to scroll, instead of scaling whole chart to fit in space

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am trying to use [Daniel Gindi's Charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and what I what I want is for the bar or line chart to only show a portion of the data, but allow the user to scroll to the right to see the rest of the data.

Right now, the chart shows ALL the data inside the view, so the bars are too small or invisible, and if there was only data points at the start of the graph, the line graph is scrunched so that you cannot see the data.

I've tried setting the xAxis.axisMaximum to a certain value, and that does display the data better, but then you cannot scroll to the right to see the rest of the chart. I want both: to see the data at a reasonable size, and to be able to scroll to the right to see the rest of the chart if the chart needs it, which it often will with my software.

Here is my bar and line chart code:

```
override func makeChart(resultChoice: chartData)
{
    let chart = getChartObject() as! BarLineChartViewBase
    chart.autoScaleMinMaxEnabled = true // I've tried this as false //!chart.autoScaleMinMaxEnabled
    chart.chartDescription?.enabled = false
    chart.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
    chart.dragEnabled = true
    chart.setScaleEnabled(true) //I've tried setting this to false
    chart.pinchZoomEnabled = true
    chart.leftAxis.axisMinimum = getAxisMinimum()
    chart.leftAxis.axisMaximum = getAxisMaximum()

    chart.clipValuesToContentEnabled = false
    let xAxis = chart.xAxis
    xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true
    xAxis.labelPosition = XAxis.LabelPosition.bottom
    chart.rightAxis.enabled = false
    xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
    xAxis.granularity = 1.0
    xAxis.labelFont = MyVariables.chartFont!
    //xAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    //xAxis.axisMaximum = 30

    //xAxis.setValuesForKeys(<#T##keyedValues: [String : Any]##[String : Any]#>)
    yAxis = chart.leftAxis
    yAxis.labelFont = MyVariables.chartFont!
    chart.rightAxis.enabled = false
    chart.legend.enabled = true
    yAxis.granularity = 1.0
    yAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    //var counter = 1.0
    var myEntries : [ChartDataEntry] = []

    var myXValues : [String] = []


    if !resultChoice.plotPoints.isEmpty
    {
        startDate = resultChoice.plotPoints[0].xValue
        for item in resultChoice.plotPoints
        {
            /*let timeString : String =
                {
                    let formatter = DateFormatter()
                    formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
                    formatter.amSymbol = "AM"
                    formatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
                    return formatter.string(from: item.xValue)
            }()
            myXValues.append(timeString)*/
            /*if(item.showXValue)
             {
             myXValues.append(timeString)
             }
             else
             {
             myXValues.append("")
             }*/
            let myEntry = getChartDataEntry(xval: item.xValue.timeIntervalSince(startDate), yval: Double(item.yValue))
            getColors(value: myEntry.y)

            //counter += 1
            myEntries.append(myEntry)

        }
        let myFormatter = MyXAxisValueFormatter(_startDate: startDate)

        xAxis.valueFormatter = myFormatter
        setYAxisFormatter()
        createSet(myEntries: myEntries)

    }

}
```

And here is my bar chart only code, to show that I did set a bar width:

```
override func createSet(myEntries: [ChartDataEntry])
{
    let chart = getChartObject() as! BarChartView
    let mySet = BarChartDataSet(values: myEntries, label: "Time Elapsing")
    mySet.colors = myColors
    mySet.valueColors = myColors
    mySet.valueFont = MyVariables.chartFont!
    setValueFormatter(set: mySet)

    let myBarChartData = BarChartData(dataSet: mySet)
    myBarChartData.barWidth = 0.8
    chart.data = myBarChartData
}
```

Also, I should note that according to my business partner, the software used to behave the way I'm trying to get it to behave now. I don't remember this, but the fact that he thinks it used to work right makes me think I must have changed a setting that caused the problem.  Also, recently I went from adding the chart entirely programmatically to adding the chart as a subview of another view, which was added through the interface builder. I don't think that should matter to this problem though.  Also, the reason my business partner liked how the data was displayed before might not be because of any setting change. I have changed the x-axis recently so that time is displayed uniformly. This change was necessary, or it would be difficult to know when an event that the chart displays happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by calling

`chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(30)`

AFTER the data has been set, and calling

`chart.scaleYEnabled = false` & `chart.scaleXEnabled = true`

when I set the other chart settings.

Comment: When i set above params, it scrolls the chart, but when i scroll it changes the  x position of chart when i stopped scrolling. Any ideas about this?